# NUXT SSR on Vercel (zeit now). How to deploy?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

Could anyone please help me to deploy Nuxt SSR app to vercel.

I've set up my vercel project with github integration.
Using `nuxt build` for command and `.nuxt` for directory.

After deployment it shows me content of *.nuxt/index.js* file.

I'm using nuxt v2.13

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding **now.json** file.

Example of its content:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "env": {
        "ON_VERCEL": "true"
    },
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "api/**/*.js",
            "use": "@now/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "nuxt.config.js",
            "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {  "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "api/index.js" },
        { "src": "/api", "dest": "api/index.js" },
        { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "$1" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have the same issue

in my nuxt.config

```
mode: "universal", target: "static"
```

now.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/now-builder",
      "config": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

but still showing directory list

https://tonysanjaya-me-9ura97wgm.vercel.app/

Comment: Are you trying to set up SSR site or a static site?  
For SSR it sould be mode: 'universal', target: 'server'

Comment: mode is deprecated now. you need to add ssr : true  instead mode: 'universal'